# Laravel - Force download with response()->download($fileLocation) not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a downloads functionality with Laravel. When the user clicks on the 'download' button, I initiate an ajax call to the controller which looks like this -

```
public function download(Resource $resource) {
    // Force download of the file
    $file_to_download   = 'https://data.domain.com/downloads/' . $resource->file_name;
    $temp_file_location =   public_path('/tmp_files/' . $resource->file_name);
    copy($file_to_download, $temp_file_location);
    return response()->download($temp_file_location)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

Chrome's inspector shows that the response gets populated with the contents of the file, but it won't trigger the actual download.

I've been trying to find an answer, but have had no success so far. Would really appreciate your help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is not going to work like that through AJAX call, why do you need to use AJAX for this, why just not open a new tab where file would download?

Comment: As Imphusius said, you cannot download files through an ajax request. You should use a GET request to force a download.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download a file from an Ajax request because Javascript is unable to save files to your filesystem out of security concerns.

There are a few good packages out there like [Jquery File Download](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)

Or you can use a traditional GET request.

Comment: Thank you, Kyle. Does that mean the only way to download a file would be by opening a new tab and exposing the downloadable file's url?

Comment: The package I linked avoids that issue by creating an Iframe in the DOM which is invisible and downloading it that way. Otherwise yes you would.