# Laravel download response is not forcing file download

Tags: php, laravel, axios, laravel-8, content-disposition

this question is related to: [Laravel - Force download with response()->download($fileLocation) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735835/laravel-force-download-with-response-downloadfilelocation-not-working)

The problem is, that I use a axios GET request (as mentioned in that thread) to initiate the browser download but it is not working. My Controller works perfectly and it returns the file correctly as I can see in the browser console:

#### The request:

[image]

#### The response

[image]

#### The image

[image]

But the browser is not starting any download.

I am using Vue/Nuxt on client-side and the axios request is called like this:

```
  download ({
    dispatch,
    commit,
    rootState,
    rootGetters
  }) {
    this.$axios.get('api/download',
      {
        params: {
          filenames: rootGetters['files/getDownloadFilenames'],
          mode: rootState.config.mode
        }
      }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

And the controller @laravel is called with the "getFileDownload" function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class DownloadController extends Controller
{
    public function getFileDownload(Request $request) {
        $filenames = $request->input('filenames');
        $mode = $request->input('mode');
        $filePaths = [];
        foreach($filenames as $filename) {
            if ($mode == 'clean') {
                array_push($filePaths, $request->user()->getName() . config('filesystems.transfer_out_clean') . '/' . $filename);
                return response()->download($filePaths[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I am using an array here is that later on I want to return a ZIP file containing multiple files, but as you can see I am just using the first path to return a single file for testing purposes.

So my question is: Why isn't this request starting a download of that image file on the client even if I use a GET request?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You can only send one content disposition and you can only return once, therefore the whole business logic is non-sense.

Comment: Please explain that. I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: The Headers apply to the javascript request, that is handle by javascript so the browser does not see that he have to download the document. The document contents are on a javascript variable including the headers. This means that in order to send the file to the user you have to handle that via javascript. Please see my answer, it give you an idea on how to do it.